# How does this answer about L. B. and werewolves in Harry Potter answer the question?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

[This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/157665/33591) was posted as an answer to the question *[How many children in Harry's year die?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/157643/33591)*. This is the text of the answer (spoilered because spoilers):

> Lavender Brown most probably didn't actually die because Fenrir Greyback had only turned her a werewolf because he is one. So technically, Lavender Brown didn't die, she only got turned into a werewolf.

The answer gives an example of someone who *doesn't* die, while the question asks for a list of who *does* die. It looks like it was meant as a comment on the previous answer, which mentions the possibility that she died.

Yet when I flagged the answer as 'not an answer', it was declined:

> declined - It's a partial answer.

So... can someone please explain how this answers the question?

Comment: It doesn't answer it and your flag shouldn't have been rejected

Comment: At a guess, because it contains at least some relevant information, and mods are cautious about removing that.  I've flagged an (older) answer the same way, because it was written more like a separate question, and gotten a similar response.

Comment: @Radhil - mods can covert answers to comments.

Comment: @Mithrandir - yeah, but those are admittedly far more removable, hideable, and losable.  Can they convert them back if needed?

Comment: @Radhil - pretty sure not.

Comment: @Radhil - They cannot

Comment: It's a *partial answer* in the sense that the question is asking "for each character in Harry's year, are they alive or dead by the end of book 7?" and the answer provides an answer in the case of one specific character.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - But it was clearly intended as a comment.

Comment: Raised a similar flag (VLQ) because It at least tried to answer by clearing up death of one character (My judgment call, was kinda divided between NAA and VLQ, went with VLQ). [Had the similar response](http://imgur.com/a/lFnVW)

Comment: I raised a custom flag requesting it to be converted to a comment, which was deemed "helpful". Your flag shouldn't have been declined. Perhaps the mod who declined would like to weigh on — _or have they already done so?_

Comment: @Valorum I've reposted your comment answer as an answer.  Just like comments don't belong in answers, answers don't belong in comments ;)

Comment: @thedarkwanderer - We tend to be a little more lenient in the latter regard than  RPG.SE.

Answer (score 2):

As Valorum [stated in a comment above](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10855/how-does-this-answer-about-l-b-and-werewolves-in-harry-potter-answer-the-quest/10885?noredirect=1#comment33502_10855):

> It doesn't answer it and your flag shouldn't have been rejected.